# Matlab simple matrix manip

Tags: matlab, if-statement, matrix

I'm new to Matlab and I want to achieve a very simple operation : I have a 792 x 1046 uint8 matrix called mg and want to convert its cells values (from 0 to 255) to values between 1 and 4 (1,2,3,4) in a new matrix called mgc accordingly to simple conditions.

Strangely, the new matrix is filled with only 1s and 2s but not any 3s or 4s...

Here is my code :

```
[x,y]=size(mg);
mgc = zeros(x,y);

for i=1:x
    for j=1:y
        if (mg(i,j)<=100) 
            mgc(i,j)=1;
        elseif (100<mg(i,j)<=110) 
            mgc(i,j)=2;
        elseif (110<mg(i,j)<=120) 
            mgc(i,j)=3;
        else
            mgc(i,j)=4;
        end
    end
end
```

If anyone could help me solve this stupid issue, it would be great ! 
THX

Comment: You need to use [`and`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/and.html) operators in your `elseif` statements.

Comment: Thanks for your reply HamtaroWarrior, I'm sure there are values greater to 110 as the matrix is from an image that I processed on Matlab... Very odd

Comment: in fact, excaza is right, didn't notice the lack of operators in your conditions.

Comment: RIGHT ! not the first time this thing happend to me, already spent so much trying to find out where the mistake was that I forgot to check the basics. Thank you excaza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use expressions such as `100<mg(i,j)<=110` in MATLAB. Instead, use something like `100<mg(i,j) && mg(i,j)<=110`.

At the moment, MATLAB is evaluating the expression `100<mg(i,j)<=110` as `(100<mg(i,j))<=110`. `(100<mg(i,j))` is going to be either one or zero (true or false), and therefore will always be <=110. So it never gets past the second else, and your array is all either 1 or 2.

---

Edit: although this answer explains the specific issue you're having, you should probably instead be using logical indexing, which would be much more efficient than a double for loop (and more idiomatic in MATLAB). See the answers from @excaza or @Benoit_11 for examples of that).

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments you need to use logical operators in your `elseif` statements. Just so you know, you can vectorize this whole for loop with those same logical operators as follows:

Let's define `mgc2` as you did for `mgc`:

```
mgc2 = zeros(x,y);
```

Then you can fill `mgc2` like this:

```
mgc2(mg<=100) =1;
mgc2(mg>100 & mg<=110) =2;
mgc2(mg>110 & mg <=120) =3;
mgc2(mg>120) =4;
```

Comment: Thx ! would you know how to use this logical indexing method with a 3D matrix ?

Comment: You're welcome! Actually it's pretty much the same thing! Try with a small 3D matrix and play around with it; logical indexing is pretty powerful and you will surely like to use it :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `and` operators:

```
% Dummy data
mg = [10 115; 125 140];

[x,y]=size(mg);
mgc = zeros(x,y);

for i=1:x
    for j=1:y
        if (mg(i,j)<=100) 
            mgc(i,j)=1;
        elseif (100 < mg(i,j) && mg(i,j) <= 110) 
            mgc(i,j)=2;
        elseif (110 < mg(i,j) && mg(i,j) <= 120) 
            mgc(i,j)=3;
        else
            mgc(i,j)=4;
        end
    end
end
```

Returns:

```
mgc =

     1     3
     4     4
```

You also don't need to use a loop here, and can leverage MATLAB's [logical indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/) instead:

```
% Dummy data
mg = [10 115; 125 140];
mgc = zeros(size(mg));

mgc(mg <= 100) = 1;
mgc((mg > 100 & mg <= 110)) = 2;
mgc((mg > 110 & mg <= 120)) = 3;
mgc(mg > 120) = 4;
```

Which returns the same matrix.

Answer (score 0):

This is because any value greater than 100 will return true for the first elseif statement.
100 < my(i,j) returns 1.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to do a double condition, you must use the `&` operator otherwise you may have false statements

```
>> x = 4

>> res = 2<x<=3

res =

     1

%%Using the `&` operator instead 

>> res = 2<x && x<=3

res =

     0
```